Connection Refused Error in OpenSearch with FastAPI and Docker Compose Setup
I’m working on a FastAPI project that integrates with OpenSearch using Docker Compose. I keep encountering a ConnectionRefusedError when trying to connect to the OpenSearch service.
Here is my setup:
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  app:
    container_name: app-search
    build: .
    command: "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - appsearchnet
    depends_on:
      - db
      - opensearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app  # Mount the project directory to /app in the container

  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - plugins.security.disabled=true
      - OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${OPENSEARCH_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - appsearchnet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -s http://localhost:9200 || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
volumes:
  opensearch-data:
networks:
  appsearchnet:
    name: appsearchnet


main.py
from db import opensearch_client

@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
        opensearch_client.create_index()

OpenSearch Client Configuration (db/opensearch_client.py):
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch

load_dotenv()

opensearch_client = OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{'host': "opensearch", 'port': 9200}],
    http_auth=('admin', 'XXXX'),
    http_compress=True,
    use_ssl=False,
    verify_certs=False,
    ssl_assert_hostname=False,
    ssl_show_warn=False
)

INDEX_NAME = "books"

def create_index():
    if not opensearch_client.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
        opensearch_client.indices.create(
            INDEX_NAME,
            body={
                "settings": {"number_of_shards": 1},
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {"type": "integer"},
                        "title": {"type": "text"},
                        "language": {"type": "keyword"},
                        "chapters": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "chapter_no": {"type": "integer"},
                                "title": {"type": "text"},
                                "content": {"type": "text"},
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )


When I run the setup, I keep getting the following error in my logs:
2024-10-21 12:51:19,796 - WARNING - HEAD http://opensearch:9200/books [status:N/A request:0.002s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 196, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    raise ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I have confirmed that the OpenSearch service is running, but my FastAPI application can’t seem to connect. It looks like it is unable to reach http://opensearch:9200.
But I can call http://localhost:9200/ in my browser and print this:
{
  "name" : "opensearch",
  "cluster_name" : "opensearch-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "kGBFpJNlReiU2qdifiZsFQ",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : "2.17.1",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "1893d20797e30110e5877170e44d42275ce5951e",
    "build_date" : "2024-09-26T21:59:32.078798875Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

If you run docker-compose up -d twice, does it come up successfully the second time?

i was getting the error while: docker-compose up --build

yes it came successfully second time after docker-compose up -d

but sometime it starts sometime doesn't, not sure when it is success and when it won't. I need to do multiple attempt of docker-compose up --build and docker-compose up -d

You have a healthcheck, which is good, but for docker to actually use it, you should use condition: service_healthy in your depends_on block (see docs).

If it inconsistently starts the first time but always starts the second time, this can mean that the application is (sometimes) starting before the database is actually running, as @M.O. notes depends_on: alone doesn't ensure it's up.  Also see Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y for other recipes.

Seems like adding condition on depends_on when service_healthy is working now.

Adding as an answer for posterity. depends_on alone doesn't guarantee that the service will wait for the database to be healthy. To wait until the healthcheck succeeds, you need a condition in the depends_on block:
services:
  app:
    container_name: app-search
    build: .
    command: "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - appsearchnet
    depends_on:
      opensearch:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app  # Mount the project directory to /app in the container

  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - plugins.security.disabled=true
      - OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${OPENSEARCH_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - appsearchnet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -s http://localhost:9200 || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
volumes:
  opensearch-data:
networks:
  appsearchnet:
    name: appsearchnet


See the Docker docs here for more information.
